# The number of elements of order $2$ in an infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

I've just proved that for $|G|$ finite, the number of elements of order $2$ is odd. But how about the case $|G|$ infinite?

(Here, there is assumption that the set of elements of order $2$ is nonempty.)

Answer (score 9):

Let $X$ be the set of elements of $G$ of order $2$ and suppose that $X$ is finite. Then the subgroup $H=\langle X \rangle$ of $G$ generated by $X$ is finite, and so if $X$ is nonempty, then $|X|$ must be odd.

To see this, note that, since the conjugacy class of any $x \in X$ is finite, the index $|G:C_G(x)|$ is finite and hence, since $X$ is finite, $|G:C_G(X)|$ is finite, and so $H/Z(H)$ is finite. But then, by a result of Schur, the commutator subgroup $H'$ of $H$ is finite and, since the abelian group $H/H'$ is generated  by elements of order $2$, it is also finite, and hence so is $H$.

Comment: With the same proof, I think you also see that if $X$ is finite, closed under conjugation, and each element of $X$ has finite order, then $\langle X \rangle$ is a finite (normal) subgroup. So the results on the number of elements of prime order also generalize to infinite groups: if a group contains elements of prime order $p$, then the number of elements of order $p$ is $\equiv -1 \mod{p}$ or infinite.

Answer (score 6):

Let $t$ be an element of order $2$ in $G$, and assume that the number of elements of order $2$ is finite. It is enough to prove that $\{x \in G: x^2 = 1\}$ contains an even number of elements. To do that, you can pair each $x \in C_G(t)$ with $xt$ and each $x \not\in C_G(t)$ with $txt^{-1}$.