# Why a group that has four elements of order two does not exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My professor said, if you remove identity element and self inverses, the number of elements of order two should be odd. So, in a group, the number of elements of order two can't be four.Why so?

Answer (score 12):

**Preliminary remarks** (motivated by bof's comment below). It is difficult to parse what you say your professor says for a few reasons. First, the identity of a group is its own inverse, so "identity and self-inverses" is redundant. Second, an element of a group is a self-inverse if and only if it is the identity or has order two. So if you "remove self-inverses" then there are no elements of order two left.

In any case, here are the facts:

**Fact 1.** If $G$ is a finite group of odd order, then $G$ has zero elements of order 2.

**Fact 2.** If $G$ is a finite group of even order, then $G$ has an odd number of elements of order 2.

**Fact 3.** If $G$ is an arbitrary group with a finite, but nonzero, number of elements of order 2, then $G$ has an odd number of elements of order 2.

So if we put it all together, we get the following description.

> If $G$ is a group, then exactly one of the following holds.
>
> 1. $G$ has no elements of order 2.
> 2. $G$ has infinitely many elements of order 2.
> 3. $G$ has an odd number of elements of order 2.

Note that Fact 3 generalizes Fact 2, *if you assume the $p=2$ case of [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), which says that a finite group of even order has an element of order 2*. However, the $p=2$ case of Cauchy's Theorem follows directly from Fact 2. So this justifies giving separate proofs of Facts 2 and 3.

So let's start the proofs.

> *Proof of Fact 1.* This follows from [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), which implies that the order of an element in a finite group always divides the order of the group.

> *Proof of Fact 2.* Partition $G$ into three pieces:
>
> Piece 1: the identity element
>
> Piece 2: the elements of order greater than 2
>
> Piece 3: the elements of order 2
>
> There are an even number of elements in piece 2 since every element in piece 2 can be paired with its inverse, which is also in piece 2 and is not equal to the original element. (Here we use the fact that $x=x^{-1}$ iff $x$ has order at most 2.)
>
> So the total number of elements in pieces 1 and 2 is odd. Since $G$ has even order, the number of elements in piece 3 is also odd.

> *Proof of Fact 3.* (See this question: [the number of elements of order 2 in an infinite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740397/the-number-of-elements-of-order-2-in-infinite-group). I will repeat the argument by Mikko Korhonen.)
>
> Let $G$ be a group and let $X$ be the elements of order *at most* 2. Assume $G$ has an element $t$ of order 2 (so $t\in X$). Partition $X$ into two pieces. Piece 1 is the elements in $X$ that commute with $t$, and piece 2 is the rest. Then we can pair each $x$ in piece 1 with $xt$, and we can pair each $x$ in piece 2 with $txt^{-1}$. (One must check that this is a well-defined pairing, i.e., if $x$ is in piece 1 then $xt$ is in piece 1 and distinct from $x$; and if $x$ is in piece 2 then $txt^{-1}$ is in piece 2 and distinct from $x$.) So both pieces have an even number of elements, hence $X$ has an even number of elements. Removing the identity, we get an odd number of elements of order 2.

Comment: @bof Yes, I must confess that I didn't fully read that part since it appeared that the question was about the number of elements of order 2. I can't see any other way of interpreting the question since, as you say, "self-inverse" and "order 2 or the identity" mean the same thing. There must be some miscommunication between the professor and student.

Comment: I suppose the question is about finite groups but it doesn't actually **say** "finite", so what happens with infinite groups? Can an infinite group have exactly two elements of order $2$?

Comment: @bof Good point (again!) It's answered here in the negative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740397/the-number-of-elements-of-order-2-in-infinite-group (actually I think this deserves an edit to the answer again...sorry to keep doing this)