# Show that an abelian group cannot have exactly 4 elements of order 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question is from the book *Abstract Algebra* by Gregory Lee.

What I got so far is:

- Abelian group is commutative.
- The answer key says suppose $a$ and $b$ are elements of this group $G$ such that they are distinct (a.k.a. $a\neq b$) and $|a|=|b|=2$

Please help me to show this.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268873/a-finite-group-of-even-order-has-an-odd-number-of-elements-of-order-2

Comment: For Abelian groups, the proof is simpler: notice that the set of elements of order $1$ or $2$ is a subgroup (due to $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$), which would end up being a subgroup of order $5$.

Comment: 2 doesn’t divide 5

Comment: It would be more interesting to prove that no group can have exactly four elements of order $2$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796395/why-a-group-that-has-four-elements-of-order-two-does-not-exist and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740397/the-number-of-elements-of-order-2-in-an-infinite-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary argument.

If $a$ and $b$ are two elements of order $2$, then there are at least three elements of order $2$: $a,b,ab$.

If $c$ is a fourth element of order $2$, then there are at least seven elements of order $2$: $a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc$.