# Groups that have a non-zero even number of elements of order two

Tags: group-theory

Are there any groups (not necessarily finite) that have a non-zero even number of elements of order two?

My attempt: since any finite group containing an element of order 2 must be of even order, hence the number of elements of order 2 must be odd, it suffices to find groups of infinite order.

I browsed through those familiar infinite groups but non of them seem to fit in the construction. How to construct such a group?

Comment: You could take the free product of two copies of $\Bbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit This fails, since such a group has infinitely many elements of order two (for instance, if $\langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = 1\rangle$ is your presentation, then $aba$ has order two as $abaaba = abba = aa = 1,$ and similarly any odd length word will have order two).

Comment: @MichaelBarz Ah, I thought it was too good to be true. I'll leave my comment up so that others don't make the same error.

Comment: The same thing happens on the Möbius group.

Comment: Now I'm intrigued to know if there are even any groups of nonzero even number of elements of even order... From what you said, such a group has to be infinite too.

Comment: This issue has already been discussed here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740397/the-number-of-elements-of-order-2-in-an-infinite-group